# Getting a varchar value even after removing it from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I encountered a strange behavior this morning and am not sure why is it happening?
My table and values :

```
create table tblA (acc varchar(10),accname varchar(10))

insert into tblA values('1','A')
insert into tblA values('2','B')
insert into tblA values('3','C')
insert into tblA values('Z','D')
insert into tblA values('4','E')
```

Query 1 to fetch acc with 1

```
select * from tblA where acc = 1
error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Z' to data type int
```

I understand the error very well.

Query 2 to fetch all numeric records

```
select * from tblA where ISNUMERIC(acc)<>0
```

gives me all records with proper numeric accounts. Excludes acc 'Z'

Query 3 to fetch acc 1 from all numeric accs

```
select * from (select * from tblA where ISNUMERIC(acc)<>0) A 
where A.acc=1
error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Z' to data type int.
```

This is what I didn't understand, how come is it showing an error for value 'Z' that is not even present in table from subquery aliased as A? I know there are work arounds like converting or casting to varchar and all, I just want to know the reason behind this behavior

Comment: is your database contains value 'z' in your acc column ?

Comment: nope, i've given the dummy table structure and the values i m using you can use them to test my queries.

Comment: Look at the query plan. I suspect your conditions have been reordered as part of optimizing the query.  SQL Does not short-circuit (or at least, does not guarantee to).

Comment: there it is. you have your ID as 'Z'. you can try using `where A.acc='1'`

Comment: @POHH :I know '1' will work, like i said, I know the work-arounds my question is why is it including as the error says 'Z' even though the subquery filters it out.

Comment: yes @Codeek now i got your question that you dont need a workaround but you are asking for the core behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you are having datatype of Id acc as varchar and you are checking acc with integer type . just pass acc as varchar.

```
select * from (select * from tblA where ISNUMERIC(acc)<>0) A 
where A.acc='1'
```

this will work fine.

here is the screenshot for the reference 
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you have run this on your own system and it works, because it's the same query that the other says doesn't work?

Comment: @Rob W. yup i can share screenshot for the same

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that your query is slightly different (you are adding the single quotations to avoid the implicit conversion). While this works, it is not really addressing the author's question, which is why the implicit conversion way of doing it is acting on a row that it logically shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion in query 3 is a filtering predicate, meaning it is performing the check to return all rows where `acc` CAN be converted to a numeric. It is not, however, returning a result set with those values converted, as it would be here:

```
select * 
from (select CONVERT(INT, acc) AS acc, accname
      from tblA 
      where ISNUMERIC(acc)<>0) A 
where A.acc=1
```

In other words, your query is still returning varchars, not integers. As a result, it may be that behind-the-scenes, the query engine is just doing the conversion on every value in the table because it will not simply follow the order of the query if it estimates it will be faster. Therefore, even though you logically should have ruled out the need to perform an integer conversion on non-integer values, the query optimizer is still doing it in the background because it thinks it will save time. This is just my speculation.

Comment: ' it may be that behind-the-scenes, the query engine is just doing the conversion on every value in the table because it will not simply follow the order of the query if it estimates it will be faster' I didn't get this statement, are you saying that the query-engine (i don't know what is it called but query-engine sounds fancy) will consider all values of a table again even if it has been filtered in a sub query? why would it do that? first it considers entire table in subquery for filtering prupose and then it will again go through entire table even if a filtered version is available?

Comment: It's interesting you keep saying that it is going through it "again." In fact, what I'm saying is that it may be that this behavior is due precisely to the query engine avoiding going through the table "again." If it's doing all operations at once, it's a single I/O operation to read the table once, compute its values, and filter the results all in one shot.

It is less efficient to first create an interim table of filtered values, which is one operation, and then perform another operation where it goes back through this temporary table and does the conversions called for by the outer query.

Comment: makes sense, atleast for now. I'll see if there are any other possible reasons for it, and only then will I be in position to confirm your answer as right one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following nested case query

`select *
from #tblA
where 1=
case when ISNUMERIC(acc)=1 then case when acc=1 then 1 end end`